# c#: overriding Equals on an object and then up casting it

Tags: c#, casting, polymorphism

Im messing around with polymorphisem and i got a weird case  I dont understand:

I have a class A that has implemetation to Equals(Object other), and class B, that inherit from A, and overrides equals, In addition, it has Equals(A other) and Equals(B other), in the main function Ive made 3 objects, A a, B b and A ab.

the code of all of it:

```
    class A
    {
        public A()
        {
        }

        public override bool Equals(Object other)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("AObject");
            return true;
        }
    };
    class B : A
    {

        public B()
        {
        }

        public override bool Equals(Object other)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("BObject");
            return true;
        }

        public bool Equals(A other)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("BA");
            return true;
        }

        public bool Equals(B other)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("BB");
            return true;
        }
    };

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            A a1 = new A();
            A ab = new B();
            B b1 = new B();


            if (ab.Equals(a1)) Console.WriteLine(1);
            if (ab.Equals(b1)) Console.WriteLine(1);
            if (ab.Equals(ab)) Console.WriteLine(1);

        }
```

Whenever I run the program, it prints BObject, which means it calls the function Equals of class B, makes sense, but for some reason treats all of the other objects it get as a parameter as Object type?

When I do the same but insted of doing it from ab I do it from b1, (i.e `if (b1.Equals(a1)) Console.WriteLine(1);`) it works prefectly fine and prints BA, so its the casting that makes it weird,
I would love if someone could explain to me why is it calling the Equals(Object other), and not Equals(A other) or Equals(B other)

Thank you!

edit: To clarify, my question is why are the diffrent object of type A and B treated like theyre from type object in the Equal function.

I understand what `A ab = new B();` does i just dont get why it uses the `Equal(Obejact other)` and not the `Equal(A other)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is use of Parent object instantiating with child class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6558335/what-is-use-of-parent-object-instantiating-with-child-class)

Comment: @JoaquinAlvarez my question isnt what ` A ab = new B(); ` does, but why it treats them like objects on the Equal function and not like A or B refrence, thank you for answering anyway!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that the compiler will first bind to the appropriate method given the compile-time types, and then any applicable overrides (not overloads) are applied at runtime.

All of the calls are bound to `A.Equals(object)` since that's the compile-time type of the variable `ab`. They are then all overridden to `B.Equals(object)` at run-time since that's the *runtime* type of `ab`.

The run-time dispatcher won't look at the actual type of `ab` and the actual type of the parameter and determine that there's a *different* overloaded method that fits the arguments better - all it can do is look for any *overrides* (of which there is only one) and dispatch to that.

In order to bind to the *overloads* in `B` that have different parameter types, you'd need to bind to them at compile-time, which is why `b1.Equals(a1)` calls `B.Equals(A)` since the compile-time type of `b1` is `B` and there is an overload that accepts an `A`.

Comment: Thank you so much! this is exacly what i was looking for! that explains why doing `((B)ab).Equals(a1)` will make the code call `Equal(A object)`. that was really helpful!